# Massey Ferguson 240 steering wheel spins without moving the tires

Tags: power-steering, tractor

I have a problem with the power steering in my Massey Ferguson 240 tractor, it was really hard to move the steering for the last couple of weeks so I stopped using the tractor to avoid causing any serious damage, today I tried to troubleshoot the problem I cleaned the steering pump cover and the wheel started moving freely, I can't tell if the problem is in the steering box or the power steering pump, what are your suggestions? where should I begin? I checked the hydraulic oil and it was on max and the oil seemed clean. [Video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOBIQDjJvb8)

Comment: I would wonder if it's in the steering box itself. There are steering arms connected on both sides of the tractor. I'm assuming nothing is happening with them at all? You aren't seeing any movement? Wiggles or otherwise?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 there are no arms [image](https://insureyourcaronline.com/images2/massey-ferguson-240/massey-ferguson-240-3.jpg), nothing happens when I move the steering... how do I test the steering pump?

Comment: Is the steering completely hydraulic on yours? What connects the steering wheel to the front tires? I see the arm coming through the engine bay of your tractor, but I don't see where it attaches. I'm assuming it goes over to the other side to tie the two together, but from there what is the device which makes it move if not a steering arm?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes it's full hydraulic, there are two hoses coming from the steering pump into the steering box, and two hoses (the output ones as I guess) are connecting the steering box with the cylinders which actually move the wheels. I will make a video in the morning just to show you what exactly I am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I am presuming that a tractor has similar steering components as my Land Rover.  If so the possible faults are -

- Universal joint broken that connects steering column to steering box.
- Splines stripped on steering box input shaft.
- Splines stripped on steering box output shaft.
- Steering box internals worn.
- Drag link disconnected from steering box output arm.
- Drag link disconnected from wheel hub carrier.

After finding out that the steering is hydraulically driven, then some of my suggestions will not be correct for your tractor.  I will leave the answer here in case it is useful for others.

Comment: You can see the steering in [this image](https://tractorsinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mf-240-overview.jpg). The main steering box sits just below the steering wheel, with the output to the right side of the tractor (it appears). There is a second linkage on the left hand side to control that wheel/tire.

Comment: @paulster2 Looks like the same components as the LR, just in different locations.

Comment: Actually, the model I have is a little bit different there is no direct connection between the wheels and steering [see this image](https://insureyourcaronline.com/images2/massey-ferguson-240/massey-ferguson-240-3.jpg)

Comment: @QuakeCore it doesn't help that your picture shows the other side of the tractor, since the steering linkage would run down the right side. Speaking of which: as opposed to cars, a direct mechanical connection of the steering wheel to the front wheels is not required for tractors. I know that many other MF tractors from the 80's have fully hydraulic steering but i'm not familiar with your 240.

Answer (score 1):

I have refilled the steering pump oil reservoir with about 0.5 liter of hydraulic fluid, and the steering wheel moves smoothly and without any problem.
I really thought that the power steering was operating on the gears/hydraulic oil just like the main hydraulic pump that moves the hydraulic arms.

[image]